# What are the events on a canvas object I can handle?

Tags: javascript, canvas, dom-events

What events on the [canvas object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) that I can handle.  In particular, I'm looking for a mouse click (or down, or up, etc) event that will give me the x and y within the canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little **[[Demo](http://jsbin.com/iqefu4/8)]**.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.onclick = function(e) {
  // mouse coordinates relative 
  // to the canvas element
  var position = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var click = {
    x: e.clientX - position.left,
    y: e.clientY - position.top
  };
};
```

Comment: That works quiet nicely in chrome, but doesn't in FF3.6.  I'd like to at least support *two* broswers.

Comment: Yep, sorry I forgot that FF doesn't have it directly. See my update.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot attach DOM events to things other than DOM objects (elements). The `canvas` is a DOM element, the things you are drawing on it are not. In order to get the specific x y coords of where the user clicked, you must attach the click event to your `canvas` element, and then compare the x,y coords of the click with the x,y coords of your `canvas` element.

Comment: Can I use the standard OnClick event with my canvas?

Comment: `@C. Ross` Yes, you can attach an event handler to the `canvas` *element* itself, just not a specific part of the `canvas`. Short answer...Yes. :)